# Blessing on fulfilling a prophecy

Tags: blessing, messiah, nevua-prophecy

Prophecy ended at around the same time blessings were introduced into Judaism, during the time of Anshei Knesses Hagdola. There were exceptions of course like Birchas Hamazon and Birchas Hatorah, but even when fulfilling a mitzvah in the Torah, a blessing was generally not said.

My question is concerning the nature of a prophet fulfilling the direct command from Hashem. Would that action get a bracha? Such as Yechezkel writing on the sticks and bringing them together, as found in chapter 37 of his book. Or Hoshea marrying a zona as in chapter 1 of his. Or perhaps only actions for the general population get brachos.

Of course, as mentioned, these two time periods did not overlap much, if at all. But if they did, did those prophets make brachos?

Besides my curiosity, there might be a practical application for this. Moshiach will come. He will be a prophet and he will fulfill Hashem's commandments. There is no reason to assume the institution of blessings will be abolished. So will he be making blessings on his fulfillments of Hashem's prophetic commands?

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure no blessings were said. It may have just been ad libed.

Comment: That could use a source. I've seen ideas like that for birchas hamazon and possibly shmona esrei, but not other brachos. But even assuming like you are saying, the question still stands.

Comment: Rashi Devarim 26:13 ולא שכחתי.  Also check the Siftei Chachamim there who explicitly says they said a bracha in their own words, that was my primary point.  (Although Tosfot Yom Tov disagrees and says the whole thing is an asmachta).  (@DoubleAA)

Comment: @Double you have any reason to think they made brachos on say teffilin and tzitzis? (FWIW It only makes the question stronger if you think they did)

Comment: @user6591 I have no sources to offer on the matter right now, so no, but a priori I wouldn't eliminate the possibility.

Comment: @Double I would be curious if you found anything. I always assumed not based on the focus the Torah and chazzal put on beis hamikdosh related mitzvos only. Bikurim also got it's amira with the mitzvah. I have more to add to this, but that was my basic assumption.

Comment: I'm not sure if קדשנו במצותיו וצונו would even apply, since the action isn't one of the Mitzvot, but a "temporary" command.

Comment: @DoubleAA I suspect that unlike Rambam who rigorously defines מצות, precluding for example, temporary commandments (cf. Shoresh 3 to SHM), that earlier authorities weren't as particular with this point. The plural, would however, likely be inappropriate in context.

Comment: @mevaqesh Adderabba, I was more concerned about 'Kiddeshanu'. Consider how for various Kohein Mitzvot they use a different formulation.